# Need to return a value from a method which is implementing java.util.Timer

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I want to return boolean value from the below method but it gives me error message saying

```
"Local variable stopped is access from within inner class;
 needs to be declared final."
```

But if I declare stopped as final I can't change it's value.

I know it is due to Timer. Please suggest !

```
public boolean requestTimer(final Club club,final String msisdn, final int time)   {

   boolean stopped=false;

   new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
      new java.util.TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
               stopped=checkStopped(club,msisdn); //this line has the   error                                
          }
      }, time);
    return stopped;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know it is due to Timer

It has nothing to do with Timer and all to do with your trying to use a local variable in an inner class. Java makes a copy of the local variable that is used in the inner class, and the two variables -- the original and its copy -- risk changing if the original is not declared final.

> But if I declare stopped as final I can't change it's value.

True. So you can't do this. A possible solution is for you to not use a local variable. Instead use a field declared in the class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the local variable form the inner class. You could access it, but must be declared final so you cannot change it once assigned.

You could modify the field of the outer class from the inner class no problem. Move the declaration to the field level:

```
    boolean stopped=false;

    public boolean requestTimer(final Club club,final String msisdn, final int time) 
    (...)
```

and this will work.

If you have a task that must run after scheduled delay and return the result, I would suggest to use [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) instead of the `TimeTask` and `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of `Timer`. Then you will get `ScheduledFuture` that will return the needed value, or would suspend the current thread if such is not yet available.

Answer (score 1):

You might (ab)use an BooleanHolder:

```
import org.omg.CORBA.BooleanHolder;
...
final BooleanHolder stopped= new BooleanHolder();
...
stopped.value = checkStopped(club,msisdn);
...
return stopped.value;
```

Thus, you have a something that is `final`, but holds a mutable value. Similar for int etc.

Comment: Also note that this will perhaps not work as expected: When you return the value, the timer might not have run yet...